# Error in setup pandas in julia : key "_IXIndexer" not found

Tags: linux, pandas, docker, cmake, julia

I'm completely new to docker or julia, and I need to build dockerfile on Linux (ubuntu 20.04) and need help. 
My dockerfile runs `RUN julia /julia/setup.jl` and get the following error:

> ERROR: LoadError: InitError: KeyError: key "_IXIndexer" not found

here is setup.jl code:

```
Pkg.init()
Pkg.add("Pandas")
Pkg.add("JLD")
# Force compile
using Pandas
using JLD

Pkg.add("ArgParse")
```

And here is full log of my error;  
(sorry for being too broad, since I do not get any sense of context)

```
Info: Attempting to create directory /root/.julia/v0.6/CMakeWrapper/deps/downloads
Info: Downloading file https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 29.2M  100 29.2M    0     0   973k      0  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:-- 4718k
Info: Done downloading file https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
Info: Attempting to create directory /root/.julia/v0.6/CMakeWrapper/deps
Info: Directory /root/.julia/v0.6/CMakeWrapper/deps already exists
Info: Attempting to create directory /root/.julia/v0.6/CMakeWrapper/deps/usr/bin
cmake version 3.7.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
INFO: Building Blosc
Info: Downloading https://github.com/stevengj/BloscBuilder/releases/download/v1.14.3+5/Blosc.v1.14.3.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz to /root/.julia/v0.6/Blosc/deps/usr/downloads/Blosc.v1.14.3.x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz...
[01:15:50] #####################################################################[01:15:50] #                                                                    [01:15:50] ####                                                                 [01:15:50] ###########                                                          [01:15:50] #########################                                            [01:15:51] ###############################################                      [01:15:51] #####################################################################[01:15:51] ######################################################################## 100.0%
INFO: Building HDF5
INFO: Package database updated
WARNING: Implicit vectorized function is deprecated in favor of compact broadcast syntax.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
 [2] @dep_vectorize_1arg(::ANY, ::ANY) at /root/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/deprecated.jl:18
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [5] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [6] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [7] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
 [8] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
 [9] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:286
 [10] _start() at ./client.jl:371
while loading /root/.julia/v0.6/Colors/src/algorithms.jl, in expression starting on line 152
WARNING: Implicit vectorized function is deprecated in favor of compact broadcast syntax.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
 [2] @dep_vectorize_1arg(::ANY, ::ANY) at /root/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/deprecated.jl:18
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [5] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [6] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [7] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
 [8] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
 [9] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:286
 [10] _start() at ./client.jl:371
while loading /root/.julia/v0.6/Colors/src/algorithms.jl, in expression starting on line 153
WARNING: Implicit vectorized function is deprecated in favor of compact broadcast syntax.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
 [2] @dep_vectorize_1arg(::ANY, ::ANY) at /root/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/deprecated.jl:18
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [5] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [6] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [7] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
 [8] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
 [9] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:286
 [10] _start() at ./client.jl:371
while loading /root/.julia/v0.6/Colors/src/algorithms.jl, in expression starting on line 154
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: KeyError: key "_IXIndexer" not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::PyCall.PyObject, ::String) at /root/.julia/v0.6/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:289
 [2] (::Pandas.##21#24)() at /root/.julia/v0.6/Pandas/src/Pandas.jl:194
 [3] __init__() at /root/.julia/v0.6/Pandas/src/Pandas.jl:26
 [4] _include_from_serialized(::String) at ./loading.jl:157
 [5] _require_from_serialized(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Bool) at ./loading.jl:200
 [6] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:498
 [7] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [8] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [9] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [10] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:305
 [11] _start() at ./client.jl:371
during initialization of module Pandas
while loading /julia/setup.jl, in expression starting on line 5
The command '/bin/sh -c julia /julia/setup.jl' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think it's problem on `using Pandas` (as indicated, line 5), so I tried inserting line in dockerfile `RUN pip install --upgrade pandas` ahead to setup.jl, but it still doesn't work. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very old Julia version (0.6).
As of today the packages simply stopped working with that version of language.

Try to upgrade Julia - that is use the current version 1.5.0. When you upgrade Pandas will work out of the box - you do not even need the `pip` command.